# How to do manual Saccharomyces tetrad separation with minimal equipment?

Tags: lab-techniques, yeast

I would like to separate the four ascospores from individual asci by manual microscopic manipulation without at micro-manipulator and a basic dissecting microscope capable of 600X total magnification and a fine needle. Is this possible? My guess is that human hands would not be steady enough. But what did they do before micro-manipulators were commonplace?

Comment: Careful centrifugation can separate tetrad from individual spores. Do you mean breaking up the tetrad and isolating individual spores.

Comment: Yes, I mean breaking up the tetrad and isolating individual spores. I am trying to do this without buying much equipment. There are complete yeast tetrad separation systems that are $$$. A micromanipulator mounted to a microscope  with 600X magnification seems to be the preferred method. I'm wondering if anyone has experience doing this technique with as little expensive equipment as possible.